# How do I return data from a javascript https request

Tags: javascript, request

How do I return data from inside an `https.request`?

Here is my https request function, which works fine:

```
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    var l = JSON.parse(d);
    console.log(l.firstName);

    //The Retuned JSON is HERE  <—————————————- HERE

  });

});

req.end();

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

//What I need is the retuned JSON file here <——————————I NEED IT HERE
```

I would normally just return some value inside each nested function but with the `https.request` I am unsure how this works.

Comment: Call a function which will have `data` as argument..

Comment: You can't return that data. Why do you need it "there"?

Comment: This is part of a single function inside of a function running in node. I need data from the request JSON to post to my DB and for another get request. I guess I could just keep going deeper inside the function, but it seems like it would be cleaner to return the data.

Comment: If you don't want to end up in "callback hell", have a look at promises.